# Split a character list based on conditions in Python Regex

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a character list in this format "EXECUTE SYS-SM-THIS-1004"

What's the efficient way to split this list based on the conditions:

1. From the list, consider the characters after EXECUTE, split them using hyphen(-) as delimiter
2. From the resulting list, first element must be equal to any one of [SYS, CSC, ISC]
3. Last word must be a 4 digit number
4. Contents between first and last words to be moved into a new list after removing the Leading and ending hyphens. Finally hyphen to be replaced with underscore.

Condition to find if the line has the work EXECUTE is working. How to check the other conditions?

```
if re.match('^\s*EXECUTE .*', line) or re.match('^\s*execute.*', line) :
```

Input:

```
a = ["EXECUTE SYS-SM-THIS-1004"]
```

Expected Output:

```
X = SYS
Y = SM_THIS
Z = SYS-SM-THIS-1004
```

Comment: that's just checking for both the cases. edited now

Comment: You can use the [`re.I`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.I) or `IGNORECASE` flag fot that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `re.match`

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = "EXECUTE SYS-SM-THIS-1004"
m = re.match(r"EXECUTE (?P<Z>(?P<X>SYS|CSC|ISC)\-(?P<Y>\S+)\-\d{4})$", s.strip())
if m:
    X = m.group("X")
    Y = m.group("Y").replace("-", "_")
    Z = m.group("Z")
    print(X, Y, Z)
```

**Output:**

```
('SYS', 'SM_THIS', 'SYS-SM-THIS-1004')
```

Comment: This does not replace `-` with `_` in `Y`, but doing this after the regex match would be trivial. But maybe use `\S+` instead of `.*?`?

Comment: Sorry did not see that info in the que.

Comment: If the match fails for "SYS|CSC|ISC", how do the error get captured

Comment: @Osceria. If it does not match it will not come inside the if condition `if m`

Comment: @Rakesh I'm just trying to understand how exactly does this regex work. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I am using regex grouping. `X = "(?P<X>SYS|CSC|ISC)", Y = "(?P<Y>\S+)", Z = "(?P<Z>(?P<X>SYS|CSC|ISC)\-(?P<Y>\S+)\-\d{4})"` in the above example you can see `?P<VARIABLE>` I use the `VARIABLE` call the group